# Selecting Pandas rows that have the same value in column 'A'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is sorted by column 'A' i.e. all repeated values come after each other, can I somehow merge rows with a bold border so that inside the bold borders all values on column 'A' are the same.
Or to highlight it with colors, make 2 alternating colors, but that it was clearly visible where the rows with one value in column 'A' end and new rows with another value begin.

I was using the Styling documentation to find a solution but no luck.
[I want it to look something like the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7aGY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following code:

```
def highlight_last_occurrence(s):
   last_occurrences = s.duplicated(keep=False) & ~s.duplicated(keep='last')
   return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in last_occurrences]


styled_df = df.style.apply(highlight_last_occurrence, subset=['ColumnA'], axis=0)
styled_df
```

And just play around with the return part in the `highlight_last_occurence(s)` part. Make sure you replace the df with whatever your dataframe is called.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of Jupyter Notebook, you could use [`df.style.set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) for this:

```py
# create boolean Series with `True` for last row each group by
# checking for each row if it equals (`Series.eq`) the next row (`Series.shift`)
m = df['A'].eq(df['A'].shift())

# create dict `styles` using dict comprehension containing each index value 
# corresponding to `True` in `m`
    # `[:-1]` excludes the very last row
    # use `'selector': 'td'` if you want to exclude the border for the index
styles = {i: [{'selector': '', 'props': 'border-bottom: 3px solid red'}] 
          for i in m[m].index[:-1]
         }

df_styled = df.style.set_table_styles(styles, overwrite=False, axis=1)
df_styled
```

**Output**

[image: red bottom border for each group]

**Data used**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

data = {'A': np.repeat(range(1,5), 2),
        'B': np.random.rand(8),
        'C': np.random.rand(8)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image: df sample]